# I am not able to find error logs and traffic logs on apache zookeeper

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I set up a zookeeper (version 3.4.6) for my solr5.4. my zoo.conf looks like this.I am not able to find error logs in `/var/log` or `var/log/zookeeper`. am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance

```
tickTime=2000 

dataDir=/var/zookeeper/

dataLogDir=/var/log/

clientPort=2181

initLimit=5

syncLimit=2

server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888

server.2=h1:2888:3888

server.3=h2:2888:3888
```

Comment: Can you provide command used for starting zookeeper server?

Comment: sudo bin/zkServer.sh start conf/zoo.cfg

Comment: I could fine log files in zoo.out located in the zookeeper directory (zookeeper.3.4.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZooKeeper uses log4j for actual logging, so you have to see your log4j.properties. The way ZK is set up by default, you can also override some stuff via JVMs system properties, so you might need to check your startup script as well.

The properties in zoo.cfg (dataDir and dataLogDir) are used for ZK application data, like the transaction log, so don't confuse that with standard log4j logging.

Comment: got it. Default logs for going to zookeeper.out file under zookeeper directory.